# Declaring gobal object in Python

Tags: python

I would like to create an object accessible from any other object without being necessary to pass it as an argument each time.

I've created an example with three classes. The first one:

```
class GlobalElement():

    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = 1
        self.prop2 = 2
    def elementsSum(self):
        return self.prop1 + self.prop2
```

The second one:

```
class LocalElement1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop4 = 4
```

The third one:

```
class LocalElement2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop5 = 5
        self.sum = None
    def runSum(self):
        self.sum = G.elementsSum()
```

The main:

```
from Glob import GlobalElement
from Loc1 import LocalElement1
from Loc2 import LocalElement2


if __name__ == '__main__':

    G = GlobalElement()
    L1 = LocalElement1()
    L2 = LocalElement2()
    L2.runSum()
```

I'm trying to access the 'G' object from the constructor of the L2 element without pass it as an argument ('L2 = LocalElement2(G)'). Obviously this is not working because the constructor of L2 doesn't know what is 'G'.

Is there anyway of doing this ? I've already trying to declare 'G' as global but still the same problem. I'm using Python 3.7.6.

Comment: Global variables are module specific, you can't access them in other modules

Comment: .. but you can import them from the module that defined them, making them available as a module level variable inside the other module. But - generally this is an anti-pattern; what are you trying to solve and why does this solution appeal to you?

Comment: Exactly. I think you could do `from Glob import G` (in `Loc2.py`) but this really is bad practice.

Comment: In the example you have put, you could not achieve what you are looking for by making LocalElement1 and LocalElement2 inherit from GlobalElement?

Comment: whilst 'prefer composition over inheritence' is a good rule, the hidden clause is 'unless you are actually encoding inheritence'.  If your local objects are more defined or developed instances of your global element (they have an 'is a' relationship), inherit.  Otherwise pass the object for composition explicitly to the constructor: that way there are no surprises.  But the fact that you are binding a local name to a method on G for use locally kind of suggests you are trying to reinvent inheritence.

Comment: Obligatory question/warning: "without pass it as an argument" *Why* do you want to do this? The usual way of combining instances is to either *compose* (via arguments) or *extend* (via inheritance) and your setup allows to easily do either with much less hassle than introducing global instances.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I'm creating a GUI application with several windows. Each window will use a Selenium object to do some tasks. I would like that this Selenium object to be accessible from each window. The example is just to show the problem in a more simple way

Comment: Note that Python also supports multiple inheritance (although called differently and technically probably not really the same). Anyway, it seems that you simplified your problem too much and we're now discussing a hypothetical problem that might have completely different solutions than your actual problem. Maybe you could update your question to reflect what you're actually trying to do.